# What do you call these supporting furniture that are used to display objects in a museum or a tech show?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call these supporting furniture that are used to display objects in a museum or a tech show? They sometimes have a protective glass and they sometimes do not, I am wondering if they are called the same regardless if they are found in museum or a tech show though like an electronics show where gadgets are displayed.

Comment: Whether I saw it in a museum, tech show or electronics show, I would call that a "pedestal." https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pedestal&ia=images&iax=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Funiquestone.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F03%2F55004_Small_Panel_Pedestal-1200x1622.jpg

Comment: The glass would be a 'display case'.

Answer (score 1):

They may be called ["pedestals"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedestal) (as noted in a comment above) or ["stands"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand):

> pedestal noun
> : the base of an upright structure
> // the *pedestal* of a statue

> stand noun
> : a frame on or in which something may be placed for support

Here is a website that makes frequent use of the term "pedestal" for these objects: https://www.gaylord.com/c/Pedestal-Cases

The glass case is often called a ["vitrine"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vitrine):

> : a glass showcase or cabinet especially for displaying fine wares or specimens

These terms may be used either at museums or at expositions (such as tech shows).

(All definitions are from Merriam-Webster online.)